# Why does glide expect GOPATH to be set?

Tags: go

I'm trying to install the dependencies for a project (on OS X), which involves calling `glide up`. However, [glide](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide) fails consistently with the following error: `[ERROR] $GOPATH is not set.`. I'm using glide version 0.12.3 and go version 1.8.1.

Why does glide require `GOPATH` to be set?

I'm new to go and glide, but from what I can tell defining $GOPATH should be optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does glide require GOPATH to be set?

Because `GOPATH` wasn't optional until Go 1.8 and glide existed before 1.8. Glide [was updated 25 days ago to handle this change](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide/pull/798), but the most recent release (`0.12.13` and what you're using) was released in [October of 2016](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide/releases/tag/v0.12.3)

Comment: Aha... that makes sense. Thanks for clearing this up!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with `glide` but GOPATH is a variable used by `go` to define where your workspace is.

As of Go 1.8.1, GOPATH defaults to a `go` subdirectory in your user's home directory. Here's the relevant commit https://github.com/golang/go/commit/74628a8b9f102bddd5078ee426efe0fd57033115

If you're using anything below Go 1.8.1 then your GOPATH is required to be set.

Also, glide doesn't seem to make any assumptions about GOPATH but it plays nicely with Go's 1.8.1 default.